# Prevent a hidden tr from breaking the td widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am collapsing table rows and using jQuery to toggle them. However, when the hidden rows are shown, the width of the `td` elements in the first `tr` are recalculated. This is exhibited on my example:

```js
$("tr:first").click(function(){
    $(this).next('tr').toggle();
});
```

```css
tr{
    display: none;
}
tr:first-of-type{
    display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="5">Hello</td><td colspan="3">World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
</table>
```

(Fiddle if preferred: http://jsfiddle.net/8u070tkf/)

How can I force the flow of the hidden row, but still toggle the visibility of the second `tr`?

Comment: `How can I force the flow of the hidden row, but still toggle the visibility of the second tr?` not really sure what this means. Do you want the first row to keep its initial width when the second row's visibility is toggled?

Comment: Can't suggest much besides adding a CSS rule for each column so they're always set at 20% or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You would have better to toggle a class and set `visibility` CSS property:

```
$("tr:first").click(function(){
    $(this).next('tr').toggleClass('shown');
});
```

CSS:

```
tr:not(:first-of-type):not(.shown){
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: This leaves whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but a few hints eventually.

you may relay on `colgroup` and `min-width` , unfortunately, display:none; hides width of content.

table-layout and width on table is something to look at too.

http://jsfiddle.net/8u070tkf/2/

```js
$("tr:first").click(function(){
    $(this).next('tr').toggle();
});
```

```css
tr{
    display: none;
}
tr:first-of-type{
    display: table-row;
}
col {
    min-width:2.2em;
}
td {
    background:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js"></script>
<table>
    <colgroup><col/><col/> <col/><col/><col/> <col/><col/> <col/></colgroup>
    <tr><td colspan="5">Hello</td><td colspan="3">World</td></tr>
    <tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
</table>
```